# jQuery: $.post not loading data from external php file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a script that calculates data from a form loaded using jQuery post but my script is not working as expected.

This is my code:

```js
//main file
function updateForm(monthsunpaid, unpaiddue, nodelay, tpenalty, idpostsave, code) {
    $.post("updatedata.php", {
            monthsunpaid: monthsunpaid,
            unpaiddue: unpaiddue,
            nodelay: nodelay,
            tpenalty: tpenalty,
            idpostsave: idpostsave,
            code: code
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $(".table1").empty().append(data);
            $('#myModaledit').modal('hide');
        });
}

 
<script >
    // want to make this code work
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nodelay").change(function() {
            var unpaiddue = $("#unpaiddue").val();
            var nodelay = $("#nodelay").val();
            var result = Number(unpaiddue) * Number(nodelay) * 0.05;
            var result = Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
            $("#tpenalty").val(result);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This data is from a php file load using the `updateForm()` function:

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="usr">UNPAID MONTHS</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="monthsunpaid"  value="<?php echo $delayed_months; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">UNPAID MONTHLY DUES</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unpaiddue"   value="<?php echo $unpaid_monthly; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">NO. OF MONTHS DELAYED</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nodelay"  value="<?php echo $months_delayed; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">TOTAL PENALTY CHARGES EQUITY</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tpenalty"  value="<?php echo $totalpenalty; ?>">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden"  id="idpostsave" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <input type="hidden"  id="code" value="<?php echo $biscode; ?>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveButton"  
onclick="updateForm($(monthsunpaid).val(), $(unpaiddue).val(), $(nodelay).val(), $(tpenalty).val(), $(idpostsave).val(), $(code).val())">SAVE</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: When you say the script is not working, what error are you getting ? Is it displayed in the console? or is it a server side error ?

Comment: Where is your element in code which have `id` `nodelay`?

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal it's here `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nodelay"  value="<?php echo $months_delayed; ?>">`

Comment: nothing happens when this code is executed. 
<script >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nodelay").change(function() {
            var unpaiddue = $("#unpaiddue").val();
            var nodelay = $("#nodelay").val();
            var result = Number(unpaiddue) * Number(nodelay) * 0.05;
            var result = Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
            $("#tpenalty").val(result);
        });
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following changes to your code to avoid issues that can be caused by mixing inline javascript and jquery. Consider delegating all event binding logic to jquery (rather than using on `onclick` in your forms HTML) by doing the following:

```js
//main file
function updateForm(monthsunpaid, unpaiddue, nodelay, tpenalty, idpostsave, code){

  $.post( "updatedata.php", { 
     monthsunpaid:monthsunpaid, 
     unpaiddue:unpaiddue, 
     nodelay:nodelay, 
     tpenalty:tpenalty, 
     idpostsave:idpostsave, 
     code:code 
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
  
     $( ".table1" ).empty().append( data );
     $('#myModaledit').modal('hide');
  });
}
  
// Shorthand for JQuery is now ready 
$(function(){ 

  $(document).on('change', "#nodelay", function(){
    var unpaiddue = $("#unpaiddue").val(); 
    var nodelay = $("#nodelay").val();  
    var result = Number(unpaiddue) * Number(nodelay) * 0.05;
    var result =   Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
   
    $("#tpenalty").val(result);
  });
  
  // Attach a submit handler to your form, which is called
  // when the user submits the form
  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
  
    updateForm( 
     $('#monthsunpaid').val(),
     $('#unpaiddue').val(), 
     $('#nodelay').val(), 
     $('#tpenalty').val(), 
     $('#idpostsave').val(), 
     $('#code').val()
    );
    
    // Prevent default form submit behaviour
    return false; 
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">UNPAID MONTHS</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="monthsunpaid"  value="<?php echo $delayed_months; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">UNPAID MONTHLY DUES</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unpaiddue"   value="<?php echo $unpaid_monthly; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">NO. OF MONTHS DELAYED</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nodelay"  value="<?php echo $months_delayed; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pwd">TOTAL PENALTY CHARGES EQUITY</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tpenalty"  value="<?php echo $totalpenalty; ?>">
</div>
<input type="hidden"  id="idpostsave" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="hidden"  id="code" value="<?php echo $biscode; ?>">
<div class="form-group">

<!-- replace button with input, leave event binding to jquery -->
<input type="submit" value="SAVE" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveButton" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I first load the form using this code below before the code shown in the post and my problem is when i put javascript in the loaded form nothing happen or event is not triggered                             
_____________________________________________________________ function editrow(id){
$.post( "editdataform.php", { idkey: id })
  .done(function( data ) {
    $( ".editdata" ).empty().append( data );
  });
   
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModaledit').modal('show')
  });
}

Comment: I first load the form using jquery $.POST  my problem is when i put some javascript in the loaded form nothing happen or event is not triggered

Comment: updated answer didn't work i think because i first load the html form using jquery $.Post before the code.

Comment: I didn't get any console error it seems that the form that loaded using jquery  jQuery.post() can't recognize in the main form.

Comment: When you say "I first load the form using jquery $.POST ", what do you mean exactly? Are you loading the form HTML via $.POST ?

Comment: yes i load file(HTML update FORM) using jQuery.post()

Answer (score 0):

Bind your event as [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). Change your code to this and hope so it will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("document").on("#nodelay", "change", function() {
            var unpaiddue = $("#unpaiddue").val();
            var nodelay = $("#nodelay").val();
            var result = Number(unpaiddue) * Number(nodelay) * 0.05;
            var result = Math.round(result * 100) / 100;
            $("#tpenalty").val(result);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I first load the form using jquery $.POST my problem is when i put some javascript in the loaded form nothing happen or event is not triggered.. i also test this code and its not also work.